# "Утеряны посвящения храмов", "храмы устроены" - можно оставить как есть?

Tags: грамотная-речь

> Мы утеряли посвящения этих храмов – то есть неизвестно, в честь каких
>   богов они устроены.

Тире я тоже вижу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Мы утеряли посвящения этих храмов"**. По-моему, написанное — не эквивалент словам "утеряли информацию о том, чему/кому посвящены эти храмы", оно корректно только если под словом "посвящение" понимается некий объект, описывающий чему/кому посвящен храм.

**"В честь каких богов они устроены"**. Написанное корректно, если речь идет именно об устройстве, а не о строительстве: Позднее в Иерусалиме был построен храм, устроенный по образцу скинии. [И. Сокольский. Что есть что в мире библейских растений // «Наука и жизнь», 2006]

Тире я тоже вижу.

Comment: Ура, мы обои видим тире! )))